# Using update handle in magento layout to set root template fails

Tags: php, magento

I am using the following to apply a new layout handle to the contacts page:

```
<update handle="test_contacts_set_root" />
```

I can verify that the layout handle is being applied.

Unfortunately the following does now work:

```
<test_contacts_set_root>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</test_contacts_set_root>
```

This is very standard layout code to change the root template.  Unforunately when applied with the custom layout handle it has no effect.

I suspect this is to do with some sort of ordering in the layout system or something.

here is the the full contents of my contacts.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="footer_links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="contacts" ifconfig="contacts/contacts/enabled"><label>Contact Us</label><url>contacts</url><title>Contact Us</title><prepare>true</prepare></action>
        </reference>
    </default>

    <contacts_index_index translate="label">
        <label>Contact Us Form</label>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
        </reference>

        <update handle="test_contacts_set_root" />

        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </contacts_index_index>

    <test_contacts_set_root>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </test_contacts_set_root>

</layout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You give 2 different instructions to the layout: first magento tries to use handle test_contacts_set_root and tries to set 1column template and later it meets command "Hey, set template to the 2columns-right.phtml" in

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
</reference>
```

Magento does not take into consideration in what order instructions are placed in xml node. So first of all it will look at handles after that blocks and only during block rendering actions are executed. You can look at Mage_Core_Model_Layout and Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update for details.

Comment: But the update handle tag appears last out of the two.  How can you ensure that the update handle is executed last

Comment: @MartyWallace update directives are always parsed first, then the instructions from the calling handle.

Comment: @benmarks Thats dumb :(  Ok, well i guess i need an alternative way to do this but i have no clue how.  Essentially i need a secondary handle to take precedence over the main layout handle

Comment: @MartyWallace you just can replace page/2columns-right.phtml with page/1column.phtml directly in contacts_index_index without any updates

Comment: I know that this is possible.  My example though was for illustration purposes only and to show that the update tag was being applied first.  I do need a solution though and replacing the root template directly is not an option.  it has to be through update

Comment: @benmarks, the reason i say it is dumb is that its called 'update' so it should be 'updating' something instead of being 'updated' itself by the main layout